Difference between maxlogins and maxsyslogins while setting limits in limits.conf
There are two options that are available for item while settings limits
1) maxlogins
2) maxsyslogins

What is the difference between these two? When should each of them be used? What is the recommended way to use them?
The manual page is not clear by what happens when we set these values. The manual page says for maxlogins, maximum number of logins for this user. While for maxsyslogins it says maximum number of all logins on system.
